# Having difficulty forecasting a tslm model

Tags: r, regression, time-series

I'm having issues forecasting a model of the following form.

```
y1 <- tslm(data_ts~ season+t+I(t^2)+I(t^3)+0)
```

It fits my data very well, but I run into a problem when attempting to do this:

```
forecast(y1,h=72)
```

This is the error that R gives me.

```
"Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action,  
 xlev = object$xlevels) : 
   variable lengths differ (found for 't')
In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 72 rows but variables found have 1000 rows"
```

As far as I can tell, this has something do with using `tslm` and having the cubic function in it. If I just use `tslm(data_ds~season+trend)` everything works out fine, but I specifically need the model mentioned earlier. How can I forecast my model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't expect the `forecast` function to guess what `t` might refer to. It understands `season` and `trend` because they are reserved names. If you use any other covariates, you need to tell forecast what their future values are. In this case:

```
forecast(y1, h=72, newdata=data.frame(t=101:172))
```

Even easier, use the pre-defined `trend` variable:

```
y1 <- tslm(data_ts ~ season + trend + I(trend^2) + I(trend^3))
forecast(y1, h=72)
```